# Resttemplate and patch, invalid

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I use spring 1.4.3

I try to call a web service

```
  @PatchMapping(value = "/members/{memberId}/card")
  public ResponseEntity updateMemberCardId(@PathVariable("memberId") Long memberId, @RequestBody String cardId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        memberService.updateMemberCardId(cardId, memberId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
  }
```

In my application,

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class ClientRestConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder, @Value("${main.server.url}") String mainServerUrl, @Value("${commerce.username}") String commerceUsername, @Value("${commerce.password}") String commercePassword,  @Value("${connection.timeout}") int timeout) {
        return builder.setConnectTimeout(timeout).setReadTimeout(timeout).basicAuthorization(commerceUsername, commercePassword).rootUri(mainServerUrl).build();
    }

}
```

In another method I do

```
String cardId = "123456789";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(cardId, headers);

ResponseEntity responseEntity =  restTemplate.patchForObject("/rest/members/1/card", entity, ResponseEntity.class);
```

I get this error

> java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH    at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:440)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:552)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]

Answer (score 17):

Building on ritesh.garg's answer:

Add the following [dependency](https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.httpcomponents%22%20AND%20a%3A%22httpclient%22) to your classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, create your `RestTemplate` like this:

```
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
```

Answer (score 7):

Http Patch is not supported by HttpUrlConnection. See [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7016595)

Way to solve this is to configure rest template to use spring's HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.

RestTemplateBuilder exposes requestfactory setter which should be used to do this.

Comment: i was in java 6... 2013... a bit old

Comment: Yea. Thats when Patch was recently introduced. And they decided to mark it as a won't fix. Having said that, Spring and apache does provide support for Patch by internally handling it as a Put. In order to use spring for that, you need to use spring's client http request factory (like i mentioned in my answer)